# MySQL IF IS NULL ERROR

Tags: mysql, if-statement, procedure

I want to test if a select-statement is null but I'am already failing with the case analysis:

```
SET @dublicate = NULL;
IF @dublicate IS NULL THEN
    SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
END IF;
```

This should ever return the selection but I just get the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error ... near 'IF @dublicate IS NULL THEN SELECT * FROM mysql.user; END IF' at line 2
```

and i really dont know whats wrong.

Many thanks in advance

KillerMelone

Comment: Are you using this in a stored program?

Comment: are you using in storeprocedure

Comment: yes.. and it works if I use 1=1 as condition (IF 1=1 THEN ...)

Comment: If I have the statement: IF 1=1 THEN SELECT ... END IF; it works but if I now add: SET @dublicate = NULL; the error appears. Don't know why

Answer (score 0):

it is working with my database put your query within `BEGIN` and `END`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure` ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE dublicate text DEFAULT NULL;
    SET dublicate := NULL;
    IF (dublicate IS NULL) THEN
    SELECT * FROM destinations;
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it. I didn't used the begin and end tags because I changed to phpMyAdmin but it seems like they aren't added automatically